# How do i connect to mysql database from another computer in VB.Net?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net

can anyone help me on how to connect to a database of another computer in same local network using vb.net? We already enable remote connection in the sql server configuration and also sql browser and we already connected with one another using wireless network. Here is our connection in vb.net

*"Data Source=NEWUSER0602akz\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sample;Integrated Security=True"* is there something wrong with this? because when i input a data it always show me the error *"An network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing to SQL Server"*

why it is always showing even though we already set the remote connection etc. can anyone help me with this? THANKS IN ADVANCED. :))

Comment: For MySQL, use the .NET connector for it. They have some good tutorials here in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html

Comment: @Bjoern is this what you are talking about the .NET connector - _"Data Source=NEWUSER0602akz\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sample;Integrated Security=True"_?

Comment: No. The .NET connectior is a piece of software from MySQL: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: @Bjoern hey sir? why is it that it always show the error _"A network-related or instance-name cannot establish a connection to sql server"_ even though we are connected with one another? Is there a problem with our connection string? _Data Source=NEWUSER0602akz\SQLEXPRESS;Database=sample;Trusted_Connection=True_ THANKS FOR YOUR IMMEDIATE REPLY SIR :))

Comment: As Kamil has replied, your connection string to a SQL server seems fine. Follow his advice to continue debugging whats going on there. My reply was aimed at the MySQL part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This connection string is ok, if NEWUSER0602akz is a server/another computer name.

Probably firewall on server is blocking connections. MSSQL uses 1433 port by default.

You should also check, if TCPIP protocol is enabled on that server. Find "SQL Server Configuration Manager" on your computer (in menu start, its probably in SQL Server 2005/2008 folder), open it and find "SQL Server Network Configuration". Turn on TCP/IP if is disabled.

You can also 
- try to connect with IP address instead of name
- check network configuration of client computer

Comment: we already set up all in the sql server config also the firewall. i think the only problem with our connection is the network connection that we made. can you help us how to set up a home group? we already try this one but when we ping the server it shows _Request time out_ so it is not connected right? please help us with this thing. i think this is our only problem. coz we didn't know how to set up a wireless network. THANKS in advanced. :)

Comment: how are we going to setup a wireless network instead of wired network.?

Comment: This is website to solve problems with programming, not networks. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: oh I'm SORRY! I didn't know. I thought its ok to ask questions like this.

Comment: Im sorry too, im too lazy to solve problems which needs more than 2-3 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

check your privacy policy if you have utm firewall, check also from router route. if your mysql server and vb.net are in the same network but unable to ping the ip address porbably you should check the router port and connection settings. configure your wifi as repeater and you will solve the problem.